# How to select the right iframe element in selenium

Tags: html, selenium, automation, payment, credit-card

Im trying to insert credit card information automatically with selenium. But I cant select the right element. The credit payment is implemented with hosted iFrames by https://docs.payone.com/display/public/PLATFORM/CA+-+Hosted+iFrames When I check the source code there is no iframe element only

`<div> <label for="cardNumber">Kartennummer</label> <span id="cardpan" class="inputIframe" style="display: inline;"> </span> </div>`

When I inspect the input field with developer tools in mozilla firefox the input fields appears.

```
<span id="cardpan" class="inputIframe" style="display: inline;"><iframe scrolling="no" src="https://secure.pay1.de/client-api/js/v1/payone_iframe.html?1640613289724" width="215px" height="31px" frameborder="0"></iframe></span>
```

Does someone have done anything like this?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page or the HTML code, not just a single element?

Comment: Can you share iframe HTML and the credit card which is inside the iframe, HTML?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its a bit difficult because the site contains a lot of personal data like shipping adress and co. Maybe this can help, https://pastebin.com/Ji3YguQ0

Comment: @cruisepandey Hope this is what you mean. https://pastebin.com/FSKfN9NB

Comment: @Quasari input type is hidden have you check that?

Comment: What are the manual steps involved to locate the desired element?

Comment: If you are doing `driver.page_resource` and printing it, please note that it won't fetch any iframe, you need to explicit copy-paste that in the HTML.

Comment: @cruisepandey I solved it, thank you for your request for 'driver.page_resource'. I was confused because firefox didnt showed me the iframe code. But the output of 'driver.page_resource' contained it.